# system sounds for iOS push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

At the moment I am using `node-apn` to send a `push notifications` from my server using the following for the sound:

```
notification.sound = "ping.aiff"
```

I'm assuming `"ping.aiff"` is a local system sound on `iOS` devices. Is there any library for other system sounds that I can define in the same way?  Or is this the only one available for a default sound.

Comment: Send `"default"`. For custom sound you will have to keep the sound file in your project.

Comment: try this payload `{
 "aps" : {
 "alert" : "message",
 "sound" : "default",
 "badge" : 0
 }
}`

Answer (score 2):

There are three basic things (`alert`, `badge`, `sound`) in payload which must have otherwise it'll miss on execution, the sample payload should be like following. [See Documentation][1]

```
{
 “aps” : {
 “alert” : “Your message here.”,
 “sound” : “default”,
 “badge” : 9
 }
}
```

the `default` keyword will play default sound of Notification, and you can also play your custom sound like `“sound” : “ping.aiff”,` Hope this will help.

Comment: What if there is no 'sound' parameter in aps object ? it will stop even default sound of push notification ? Currently, no sound is played in my push notification .. do you think this is because of no sound parameters ?
Is this compulsory > “sound” : “default” ?

Answer (score 1):

`default` is the only one available, and it can change according to what the user has configured in their system settings, but it doesn't depend on the app to play a "different default".

Whatever other sound you want to play, you need to include it in your app bundle and send it along the remote push notification `aps.sound:"custom.aiff"`.

More info on [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW10).